# Custom facebook integration with .net

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

Am trying to create a facebook plugin for a desktop application that we have, and this app will only be used by 1 facebook account to post results from it to the facebook page of the app.
It would be submitting on behalf of the app and not the user , so no user login is needed ( Except for the original user who manages the page )

The problem I'm having is to review a submission with new permissions, facebook requires screenshots of the app running, how do I get that, if I don't have permissions to actually use those features, I tried to create a test user with the "manage_pages" permission and I get an error.

Comment: If only one user is going to use the app you don't need to submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WizKid , I wasn't aware of that, I was able to generate a token with the permission needed from the graph explorer ( I chose my app from the dropdown ) , and from within my app, I call graph api to exchange the short lived token for a long lived token that lasts "hopefully" 60 days , also need the app id and secret, and I was good to go